# BigCommerce Checkout window.stencilBootstrap is not a function

Tags: webpack, bigcommerce

I'm using the roots theme for BigCommerce. I seem to have an error on the checkout part - Uncaught TypeError: window.stencilBootstrap is not a function (Chrome Browser). Not sure what could be causing this. Build and all pages load and work fine, but would like to stop this error from showing on console for checkout. Have tried other themes, and they don't have the same issue. Could possibly be a webpack setting, but not sure. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This typically occurs when you have a syntax error breaking one of your JavaScript files. What are you running on your checkout page? Are you using Developer Checkout, Optimized One Page Checkout? There are different checkout configurations which run scripts in different ways, it would help if you could post as many pertinent files as possible.

Comment: Hi Mikhail. Thanks for getting back. I'm running the default one page checkout. I'm using the roots theme [link](https://roots-default-demo.mybigcommerce.com/) No changes have been made, but on checkout both on local host and on the live instance I'm seeing the error on chrome console.